# Python error "'int' object is not callable"

Tags: python, function, while-loop, sequence

I wrote some code for a program that gives me the values of a sequence I defined as a function, `f(x)`, but when I run it a error pops saying `'int' object is not callable`". Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

```
def f(x):
    if x%2==0:
        return x/2
    else:
        return 3*x+1
limite=int(input("parar en: "))   
x=int(input("a1: "))
print(x)
n=1
while n<=limite:
    f=f(x)
    print(f)
    n=n+1
print("fin")
```

Answer (score 5):

You're reassigning `f` within the while loop, to the result of calling `f(x)`, which indeed an integer. So, the second time through the loop, `f` is an integer rather than a function.

I suspect you simply meant:

```
x = f(x)
print x
```

Comment: Javier, also you definitely should to take a look on PEP-0008 document: it defines the coding guidelines, which are respecting by all Python programmers.